# Is this idiomatic F# for a fairly quick infinite recursive sequence?

Tags: f#, immutability, seq

Whilst solving [the 12th project euler problem](http://projecteuler.net/problem=12) I set about making an infinite sequence to get successive triangular numbers. My first attempt was:

```
let slowTriangularNumbers =

  let rec triangularNumbersFrom n = 
    seq { 
      yield seq { 0 .. n } |> Seq.sum
      yield! triangularNumbersFrom (n + 1) 
    }

   triangularNumbersFrom 1
```

This turned out to be very slow - each time getting the next item it had to compute all of the additions leading up to `n`.

My next attempt was:

```
let fasterTriangularNumbers =

  let cache = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, int>()
  cache.[0] <- 0         

  let rec triangularNumbersFrom n = 
  seq { 
    cache.[n] <- cache.[n - 1] + n                   
    yield cache.[n]
    yield! triangularNumbersFrom (n + 1) 
  }

  triangularNumbersFrom 1
```

Introducing the mutable dictionary has speeded it up considerably, but is this normal to have a mutable collection, or is there another way I could have represented state?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is more idiomatic:

```
Seq.unfold (fun (i, n) -> Some(n, (i+1, n+i))) (2, 1)
```

You might prefer this alternative:

```
seq { 2 .. System.Int32.MaxValue }
|> Seq.scan (+) 1
```

Comment: I guess this is equivalent to:
let rec loop(n, diff) = seq { 
                yield n        
                yield! loop(n + diff, diff + 1) }
            loop(1, 2)
which was provided by Tomas Petricek in another answer. Would you mind explaining what "Some" is doing here?

Comment: @NickL `Seq.unfold` calls the specified function iteratively (but lazily!) until it returns `None`. By always returning `Some`, Jon's implementation produces an infinite sequence.

Comment: @NickL: The main advantage over writing a sequence expression by hand (other than brevity) is the assurance that there are no tail call issues. You can easily write sequence expressions that leak stack space resulting in a stack overflow. That problem does not exist if you use `Seq.unfold`.